# How to retrieve pure URL of images that attachs in posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to get pure url of images in post's attachments. when wp_get_attachment_image give me codes like these `<img src="" ... height="" width="" title="" alt="" />`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) instead. It returns an array with the src, height and width attributes.